# Deleting file created from mysql

Tags: sql, permissions, filesystems, mysql

I executed the query in mysql as

```
select * into outfile "/tmp/results.out" from table_x;
```

which in-turn wrote all the records in that table to the file in /tmp directory. The file was created with the following permissions.

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mysql mysql 6.6K Nov 14 10:14 /tmp/results.out
```

I know that it is not possible to delete this file from my login. But I tried removing this from MySQL, but I get the following error message:

```
mysql> system rm /tmp/results.out
rm: cannot remove `/tmp/results.out': Operation not permitted
```

PS: I do not have root permissions.

Comment: Did you try using your mysql admin user?

Comment: I'm not much into this, but, can you get some grant?!!! Like, GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON whatever ...

Comment: Please add unix tag to the question, it may attract active unix users who may have a good idea about this problem.

Comment: Have you tried loggin in using SFTP if your host allows, I had a similar problem with MySQL backup files, but SFTP grants you greater permissions (depending which host you are on)

Answer (score 1):

The file's owner group is mysql.   Please use the `id` command to find out another user of that group and try deleting it.  It appears that the user ID you are using to delete the file may not have write access on tmp directory.

Are you able to truncate the contents of the file? **Please do this only if you don't want the results.out file in /tmp/**

```
echo " " > /tmp/results.out
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always just overwrite the file the same way you created it with something small and harmless.

It is common practice on unix systems to clear out /tmp/* on reboot, so it won't stay there forever either.

Comment: >You could always just overwrite the file the same way you created it with something small and harmless.

ERROR 1086 (HY000): File '/tmp/example.txt' already exists